# MS Chart Control

Tags: asp.net

I am using MS Chart control in asp.net 4.0 application.In that dates are being displayed on Xaxis and count is displayed on Y axis.
If there no data for a specific date its displaying minimum date like "30-12-1899" . Let me know how to display information on the graph without these minimum dae values.

Below is the chart link which I am using in my application http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c&displaylang=en

Thanks,
Hima

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are adding points with zero as the X value.  This gets translated to DateTime.MinValue which will give you the strange date.  Try using double.NaN or just don't add points if there is no data.

Are you able to post the code you are using to create your chart?  That will help troubleshoot your problem.